# convert jQuery tree view to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tree, treeview

I have this jQuery function that I'm trying to convert to AngularJS. The function turns nested lists into a tree view structure. I have looked at several examples that create the tree completely in the controller or directive. I already have an HTML structure that I want to transform into a tree structure. I want the tree to be able to expand as more HTML elements are added. Also, the function can have no jQuery dependency. Can this be done without having classes or directives in every list element? Here is the jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
$('.tree li ul li').hide();
$('.tree ul li:first').show();
$('.tree li').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('> ul > li').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('> ul > li').hide('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).find('> ul > li').show('fast');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
   });
});

$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="tree">
<li >List 1
    <ul >
        <li>element 1</li>
        <li>element 2</li>
        <li>element 3</li>
        <li>sub-list 1
            <ul >
                <li>sub-element 1</li>
                <li>sub-element 2</li>
                <li>sub-element 3</li>
                <li>sub-element 4</li>
                <li>sub-element 5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>element 4</li>
        <li>element 5</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li >List 2
    <ul >
        <li>element 1</li>
        <li>element 2</li>
        <li>element 3</li>
        <li>element 4</li>
        <li>element 5</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is what I have so far, and I admit is isn't much:

```
tree.directive('treeView',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        elem.bind('click',function(){
            elem.children().hide();
        });
    }
  }
});
```

I know the Angular way is not to target DOM elements and that is why I'm having problems understanding how to move forward. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Make a fiddle - much easier for the people trying to help you

Comment: ""I want the tree to be able to expand as more HTML elements are added"" -> If this is what it sounds like, its a huge indicator that you need a model, yes you can do it in the "OLD HACK THE DOM" way... but you will end up with something AWFUL!.... Have a look at: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree Which lets you take full control over how Tree maps to the html. -> http://plnkr.co/edit/YhQ20OEWI8Ff6baYyQgX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the link. It pointed me in the right direction. I know hacking the DOM was not the right way in Angular but I didn't know how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

This feels dirty :-) There is no data here, only DOM elements, not sure how much use this is.

This will give you the expand collapse behavior

css:

```
div.treeview li.collapsed ul {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
angular.module('treetestApp')
    .directive('treeView', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div class="treeview" ng-transclude></div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.target.tagName === "LI" && e.target.childElementCount) {
                        $(e.target).toggleClass('collapsed');
                    }
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I agree with you that it might not be a good fit for Angular since there is no data to deal with. I was just trying to get my head around how angular works with a hands on example. Thanks